Flutter sqlite hata
hello flutter i get this error when trying to record with sqlite can you help me solve it?
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\asus.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3ff7c40156b4c9a12e03921ad97ad6a2\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\asus.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3ff7c40156b4c9a12e03921ad97ad6a2\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

                                                                                                                     I checked the Android SDK

I also checked the versions
